# ember js how to remove the hash tag in my url

Tags: ember.js

I have seen an answer to this question and was directed to the [Ember API Docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Location.html) for using the browser's `history.pushState` ability

Apparently I need to add this code to my `router.js` file

```
App.Router.reopen({
  location: 'auto'
});
```

However, doing so breaks my app!  It is a very simple app so far, since I am still only learning... so its basically just a default installation with only 4 templates, 4 routes.  I am using Ember App Kit which, I noticed initializes the router slightly differently than the ember guides describes.

Is there something different I need to do? or is there something I am doing wrong in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok... I found the answer, for anyone who might run into this same issue.

Ember app kit seems to define the router in a variable just called `Router`, so I don't need to use the conventional naming requirements.

All that needs to be added to the router.js is this:

```
Router.reopen({
  location: 'auto'
});
```

:D